# Sharepoint online token empty in extSTS

Tags: sharepoint, token

I try to get token in sharepoint by webpart, but it return empty value, I did the code below.

```
/**
* Metodo que gerará o token
*/
getTokenSharepoint() {  
var username="";
var password="";
var siteCollUrl="https://bbtecno.sharepoint.com";
var loginUrl = "https://bbtecno.sharepoint.com/_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0";
var token;
var digest;
var requestBody='<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis- 
open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">'
          +'<s:Header>'
          +'    <a:Action 
  s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue</a:Action>'
          +'    <a:ReplyTo>'
          +'      <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>'
          +'    </a:ReplyTo>'
          +'    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf</a:To>'
          +'    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1"'
          +'       xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity- 
  secext-1.0.xsd">'
          +'      <o:UsernameToken>'
          +'        <o:Username>'+username+'</o:Username>'
          +'        <o:Password>'+password+'</o:Password>'
          +'      </o:UsernameToken>'
          +'    </o:Security>'
          +'  </s:Header>'
          +'  <s:Body>'
          +'    <t:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">'
          +'      <wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">'
          +'        <a:EndpointReference>'
          +'          <a:Address>'+siteCollUrl+'</a:Address>'
          +'        </a:EndpointReference>'
          +'      </wsp:AppliesTo>'
          +'      <t:KeyType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/NoProofKey</t:KeyType>'
          +'      <t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</t:RequestType>'
          +'      <t:TokenType>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion</t:TokenType>'
          +'    </t:RequestSecurityToken>'
          +'  </s:Body>'
          +'</s:Envelope>';

  const itemHeader: any = {
      'Accept': 'text/html,application/soap+xml;odata=nometadata',
      'Content-type': 'application/xml;odata=verbose',
      'odata-version': '3.0',
      "X-HTTP-Method": "POST", 
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    };

  const spHttpClientOptions: ISPHttpClientOptions = {

      "body": requestBody,
      "method": 'POST',
      "mode": 'cors'
  };
  alert('estou aqui 1');
  this.context.httpClient.post("https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf" , 
  SPHttpClient.configurations.v1, spHttpClientOptions)
  .then(data => {
    var result: any[];
    if(data.status == 200)
    {
      alert("teste" +  JSON.stringify(data.text()));
      return data.text(); //returning the XML text of the response
    }
    else
    {
      return "";
    }
  });
}
```

Could you help me?

Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) is an algorithm that can identify and block dubious cross-origin resource loads in web browsers before they reach the web page. CORB reduces the risk of leaking sensitive data by keeping it further from cross-origin web pages. In most browsers, it keeps such data out of untrusted script execution contexts. In browsers with Site Isolation, it can keep such data out of untrusted renderer processes entirely, helping even against side channel attacks like Spectre.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I try by jquery and I don't get success, because it's generate CORS problem.

$.ajax({ 
          'url': 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf', 
          dataType: 'text', 
          type: 'POST',

```
      'data': '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-      envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><s:Header><a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue</a:Action><a:MessageID>urn:uuid:40c1407d-b2a4-4e05-8248-8a92b71102b6</a:MessageID><a:ReplyTo><a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address></a:ReplyTo><a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf</a:To><o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-69882db9-2d6b-45d3-b016-c2156cb6c01d-1"><o:Username>' + username + '</o:Username><o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">' + password + '</o:Password></o:UsernameToken></o:Security></s:Header><s:Body><t:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust"><wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"><a:EndpointReference><a:Address>https://bbtecno.sharepoint.com/_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0</a:Address></a:EndpointReference></wsp:AppliesTo><t:KeyType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/NoProofKey</t:KeyType><t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</t:RequestType><t:TokenType>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion</t:TokenType></t:RequestSecurityToken></s:Body></s:Envelope>', 


      headers: {         
      'Accept': 'text/html,application/soap+xml;odata=nometadata',
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"  }, 
      success: function (result) { 
      var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(result); 
      var xml = $(xmlDoc); 
          var binToken = xml.find("wsse\\:BinarySecurityToken").text(); 
          alert(binToken); 
          //CallSPOnline(binToken, tenantName); 
      } 
  });
```

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf' from origin 'https://bbtecno.sharepoint.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Thanks